# Booting twrp.img with fastboot doesn't work "FAILED (remote: unknown command)

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot, lg-g6

I am trying to boot twrp.img on my LG G6 ThinQ using adb and fastboot. I reboot into fastboot mode and do:

`fastboot boot ../users/******/downloads/twrp.img`

and then it says

```
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.500s]
booting...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.524s
```

My phone doesn't have root or bootloader unlocked and platform-tools is version r26

Note: `fastboot -c "lge.kcal=0|0|0|x" boot ../users/******/downloads/twrp.img` also doesn't work

Comment: Pretty sure you need the bootloader unlocked for this to work.

Comment: @acejavelin when I try to unlock it with `fastboot OEM unlock` it says failed (remote: unknown command) and lg doesn't have bootloader "unlock.bin" generator.

Comment: @WorldOfFun Boot into the device and enable oem unlock and usb debugging from dev settings. If you can't boot into the OS, try flashing the stock ROM. If you can't, then you are screwed.

Comment: @acejavelin I already did that on the phone. Guess I can't get twrp or custom os ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Turned out I was actually in `fastbootd` mode. Once you reboot into `fastboot` (without the "d" at the end) the problem is solved.